# How to use keyboard in pygame?

Tags: keyboard, pygame

I tried the simple script below, but I get no response. Maybe I don't understand what pygame is capable of doing. I simply want to assign a certain function to a certain key. Like if I press the letter 'h' I want "Bye" to print on the screen or if I press 'g' then play a certain song. And so on and so on...

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
print K_h #It prints 104
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_h:
                print "Bye" #Nothing is printed when I press h key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_h:
                print "bye"
```

for what ever reason for me atleast it seems the event command wouldn't work with out the use of a screen even if it has no purpose this will get you the results you want.

Comment: Your right Ryan! I added, gameSurface=pygame.display.set_mode((440,480)) at top of while statement and pygame.display.update() at the bottom.